# Halachic implications of moving Lag Ba'Omer

Tags: halacha, lag-ba-omer

The [Israeli Rabbanut has requested](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/180488#.U3OP33V51ys) that Lag Baomer celebrations this year be postponed to Sunday night, instead of Saturday night.

Does this affect shaving on Friday? Are people who keep the second half of sefira allowed to join in the celebrations? Are there any differences on the actual day of Lag Baomer?

Comment: I'm sure the Rabbanut addressed these issues in its _psak_. Can anyone find the original?

Comment: At least this way those keeping "first half" are able to participate in the festivities.

Comment: Great question. I was thinking the same thing